# Convert buffer base64 -> utf8 encoding node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, utf-8, base64

My app imports all the messages from the Notes folder of GMail. I use imap npm module for that.

Using the example from their github page I get all the contents of a message into a buffer:

```
 stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
     count += chunk.length;
     buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
 });
```

However, what I get are sentences like

```
  0KHQvdCw0YfQsNC70LAg0YHQvtC30LTQsNC10YLRgdGPINGA0LXRiNC10YLQutCwINC/0YDQvtGB 0YLRgNCw0L3RgdGC0LLQsCDQstC+0L7QsdGA0LDQttC10L3QuNGPLiZuYnNwOzxkaXY+PGJyPjwv ZGl2PjxkaXY+0JfQsNGC0LXQvCDQvdCwI
```

(wrong conversion from Russian)

I found out that these are the snippets of text encoded in base64 and in order to read them I need to convert it from base64 to utf8.

There is also sometimes an annoying = character that appears from nowhere...

```
 letting them f= all on her shoulders
```

Do you know how I could get rid of those two problems?

Thank you!

Comment: In order to convert from base64 to utf8 you can use `(new Buffer(original, 'base64')).toString('utf8')`. Could you provide more details about the `=` problem?

Comment: @jabclab this works, but only for the buffers that contain russian only. if there's a buffer that has only english text or english and russian, it produces gibberish. i guess i need to run some script before the conversion to identify the encoding, right?

Comment: @jabclab regarding the = problem – for some reason sometimes the = sign just gets inserted randomly in the text. i can't seem to find where exactly it appears... thank you!

Comment: @jabclab could you pls post it as an answer as that worked really well for me?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In order to convert from a base64 encoded `String` to utf8 you can use the following:

```
var base64encoded = '0KHQvdCw0YfQsNC70LAg0YHQvtC30LTQsNC10YLRgdGPINGA0LXRiNC10YLQutCwINC/0YDQvtGB 0YLRgNCw0L3RgdGC0LLQsCDQstC+0L7QsdGA0LDQttC10L3QuNGPLiZuYnNwOzxkaXY+PGJyPjwv ZGl2PjxkaXY+0JfQsNGC0LXQvCDQvdCwI';

var utf8encoded = (new Buffer(base64encoded, 'base64')).toString('utf8');
```

Comment: `new Buffer()` is deprecated with *Stability:0*, see [mido's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40929309/1168315).

Answer (score 37):

[`new Buffer(...)`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding) has been deprecated for a while now, go for [`Buffer.from(...)`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding)

a simple example might be:

```
var utf8encoded = Buffer.from(base64encoded, 'base64').toString('utf8');
```

Comment: This only works if base64encoded is a string.  If it's already a buffer you get the same encoded value out as what went in.  Only thing I've found is to dump the already-encoded buffer to a base64, read it back into the Buffer.from(), and dump it back out as, finally, the plaintext string.